# Get the object from a StackPanel by index - Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, stackpanel

I have a list of labels in a stack panel.

Is there a way to get an item by its index or its position in the panel.

**Example :**

```
x = 5;
Label l = (Label) panel.Children[x];
```

**Environment**

- Silverlight 5
- InBrowser Control

Comment: you can get item by index, exactly the way you post in **Example** section above. What was the problem with that code?

Comment: damm it, when I did this originally VS was throwing an error. I should close this question